how to use spring security OAuth for validating token using x5t
I am working with an Identity Provider (IDP) server which issues Access tokens with following attributes
KID: <env_name>
X5T: X509 Thumbprint of the the signing key
IDP Provider also has endpoint
OAuth JWT Access Token Thumbprint Certificate Endpoint: /ext/oauth/x509/x5t?v=
Using this I can obtain the Public Key used to sign the JWT and use it for validation.
I am trying to find out if there is a way to handle this in Spring Boot and Spring Security or what is the best way to handle validation.

BTW: spring-security.oauth2 i send of life since 2022. You should upgrade your application to Spring Security 6,
